# Append to outermost element matched by selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table in my document, which may or may not contain multiple nested tables. Each table (both outer and possible inner) contain tbody tags. I want to match the outermost tbody tag.

Below is a sample document:

```
<table id="shippingContainer">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

In this case I have JQuery selector selecting the outermost table. I want to select the tbody element associated with that table, but not any of the tbody elements inside the nested tables.

My original selector was simply:

```
$("#shippingContainer").find("tbody");
```

And this doesn't work for obvious reasons. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) to achieve that:

```
$("#shippingContainer > tbody");
```

This will match the `<tbody>` element that's a direct child of your table.

Comment: That's really cool! I didn't know about this selector. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use a child selector, as below:

**This will select the first tbody element in your shippingContainer table:**

```
//This will select the first tbody element (of your main table)
$("#shippingContainer > tbody")
```

**This will select the nested tbody element within your main table:**

```
//This will select the tbody element within the table (the inner table)
$("#shippingContainer").find('table > tbody')
```

[**Read more on child selectors here**](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Comment: That's what I mean it for - I didn't mean for the two to seem equivalent. :)

Comment: I deleted my comment once I read it a little more closely and realized your intention.  Thanks for clarifying it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `children` instead of `find`.

```
$("#shippingContainer").children("tbody");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
$("#shippingContainer").find("tbody").first();
```